# Hive table with multiple partitions

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table (data_table) with multiple partition columns year/month/monthkey.

Directories look something like year=2017/month=08/monthkey=2017-08/files.parquet

Which of the below queries would be faster?

`select count(*) from data_table where monthkey='2017-08'`

or

`select count(*) from data_table where monthkey='2017-08' and year = '2017' and month = '08'`

I think the initial time taken by hadoop take to find the required directories in the first case would be more. But want to confirm

Comment: I confirm it's true. It takes a lot of time scanning all upper level (year) directories in the first case.

Comment: @leftjoin - what are you talking about?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I just want to say that it's true. Really it works slower if upper partitions was not specified in the query. I'm not sure whether it scanning directories or looking into metadata only, but it works slower than if when upper partition specified as well, even if sub partition is unique.

Comment: @leftjoin - No way. We're talking here on a query against the metastore.

Comment: The query is not necessarily metastore-only. I believe count(*) here is just to simplify example. And what if table is not analyzed?

Comment: @leftjoin - You are mixing between data and metadata operations. The first step is finding the relevant partitions, which is a metadata operation. The second step is scanning the directories pointed by the partitions that was found in the first step, which is a data operation. The difference between these queries is in the first step only.

Answer (score 5):

Finding the relevant partitions is a metastore operation and **not** a file system operation.
It is done by querying the metasore and **not** by scanning the directories.
The metasore query of the first use-case will most likely be faster than the second use-case but in any case we are talking here on fractions of a second.

#### Demo

```
create external table t100k(i int)
partitioned by (x int,y int,xy string)
;
```

---

```
explain dependency select count(*) from t100k where xy='100-1000';
```

The query that was issued against the metastore:

```
select "PARTITIONS"."PART_ID" 
from "PARTITIONS"  
inner join "TBLS" on "PARTITIONS"."TBL_ID" = "TBLS"."TBL_ID"     and "TBLS"."TBL_NAME" = 't100k'   
inner join "DBS" on "TBLS"."DB_ID" = "DBS"."DB_ID"      and "DBS"."NAME" = 'local_db' 
inner join "PARTITION_KEY_VALS" "FILTER2" on "FILTER2"."PART_ID" = "PARTITIONS"."PART_ID" and "FILTER2"."INTEGER_IDX" = 2 
where (("FILTER2"."PART_KEY_VAL" = '100-1000'))
```

---

```
explain dependency select count(*) from t100k where x=100 and y=1000 and xy='100-1000';
```

---

The query that was issued against the metastore:

```
select "PARTITIONS"."PART_ID" 
from "PARTITIONS"  
inner join "TBLS" on "PARTITIONS"."TBL_ID" = "TBLS"."TBL_ID"     and "TBLS"."TBL_NAME" = 't100k'   
inner join "DBS" on "TBLS"."DB_ID" = "DBS"."DB_ID"      and "DBS"."NAME" = 'local_db' 
inner join "PARTITION_KEY_VALS" "FILTER0" on "FILTER0"."PART_ID" = "PARTITIONS"."PART_ID" and "FILTER0"."INTEGER_IDX" = 0 
inner join "PARTITION_KEY_VALS" "FILTER1" on "FILTER1"."PART_ID" = "PARTITIONS"."PART_ID" and "FILTER1"."INTEGER_IDX" = 1 
inner join "PARTITION_KEY_VALS" "FILTER2" on "FILTER2"."PART_ID" = "PARTITIONS"."PART_ID" and "FILTER2"."INTEGER_IDX" = 2 
where ( ( (((case when "FILTER0"."PART_KEY_VAL" <> '__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__' then cast("FILTER0"."PART_KEY_VAL" as decimal(21,0)) else null end) = 100) 
and ((case when "FILTER1"."PART_KEY_VAL" <> '__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__' then cast("FILTER1"."PART_KEY_VAL" as decimal(21,0)) else null end) = 1000))  
and ("FILTER2"."PART_KEY_VAL" = '100-1000')) )
```

Comment: Filesystem should also be scanned to determine files, sizes to calculate how many mappers to start.

Comment: @leftjoin - only **after** the partitions are determined and the relevant directories are known

Comment: Sure, but the question was about query speed, not about metastore query speed. You are talking about metastore only

Comment: @leftjoin, where exactly do you see a difference between these queries except for the metadata queries issued against the metastore?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Completely agreed. If you see the query, he is using the most granular partition in both the query. So, metastore db will pass the same hdfs location for both tables. So, the data being scanned is of equal volume.

Comment: Upvoted. Beautiful explanation of the inner workings.

Answer (score 0):

Since comment will change the formatting, hence posting here.
Kindly accept @Dudu's reply. Please execute the below on metastore DB (mysql in my case):

```
mysql> select part_id, location, tbl_id, part_name from PARTITIONS as P inner join SDS as S on P.SD_ID = S.SD_ID where P.TBL_ID = 472;
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| part_id | location                                                                | tbl_id | part_name                            |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|       7 | hdfs://hostname:8020/tmp/multi_part/2011/01/2011-01 |    472 | year=2011/month=1/year_month=2011-01 |
|       9 | hdfs://hostname:8020/tmp/multi_part/2012/01/2012-01 |    472 | year=2012/month=1/year_month=2012-01 |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The location from both the queries will pull data from same hdfs directory.
The only difference in speed will be from the metastore DB query that is already explained in Dudu's answer.